# Playframework: Type mismatch found scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result] required: play.api.mvc.Result

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

I have the following code in my controller in PlayFramework:

```
  def auth = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    {

      val authRequest = request.body.validate[AuthRequest]
      authRequest.fold(
        errors => Future(BadRequest),
        auth => {
          credentialsManager.checkEmailPassword(auth.email, auth.password).map {

            case Some(credential: Credentials) => {

              sessionManager.createSession(credential.authAccountId).map { //Throws an error
                case Some(authResponse: AuthResponse) => Ok(Json.toJson(authResponse))
                case None => InternalServerError

              }

            }

            case (None) => Unauthorized
          }

        })
    }
  }
```

I get the following error at the line with error comment above:

```
Type Mismatch:
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result
[error]               sessionManager.createSession(credential.authAccountId).map {
```

The createSession call there returns a `Future[Option[Object]]` but I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does your `credentialsManager.checkEmailPassword` method returns?

Comment: It returns a `Future[Option[Credentials]]` and is defined as `def checkEmailPassword(email: String, password: String): Future[Option[Credentials]]`

Comment: change `.map` to `.flatMap` in line `credentialsManager.checkEmailPassword(auth.email, auth.password).map` and `case (None) => Unauthorized` to `case None => Future(Unauthorized)`

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Can you please also explain the reasoning behind it? I would assume that it flattens the outer `Future[Option[Credentials]]` but how does that affect the inner map/return type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:
Change `.map` to `.flatMap` in line `credentialsManager.checkEmailPassword(auth.email, auth.password).map` and `case (None) => Unauthorized` to `case None => Future(Unauthorized)`

Explanation:

`credentialsManager.checkEmailPassword(auth.email, auth.password)` returns a `Future[Option[Credentials]]` and mapping on that will always return a `Future` and inside it `sessionManager.createSession(credential.authAccountId)` also returns a `Future` So, final outcome of `credentialsManager.checkEmailPassword(auth.email, auth.password)` was `Future[Future[something]]` to avoid such situations you can instead `flatten` it and then `map` it and it can be done in a single step by `flatmap`

Comment: Worth to notice that `flatten` on futures will be available in Scala 2.12 https://github.com/viktorklang/blog/blob/master/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-1.md. Now you have to `flatMap(identity)`

Comment: well, `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` are some operations available on monads itself.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but this should work:

```
def auth = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
{

  val authRequest = request.body.validate[AuthRequest]
  authRequest.fold(
    errors => Future(BadRequest),
    auth => {
      credentialsManager.checkEmailPassword(auth.email, auth.password).flatMap { //flatMap

        case Some(credential: Credentials) => {

          sessionManager.createSession(credential.authAccountId).map {
            case Some(authResponse: AuthResponse) => Ok(Json.toJson(authResponse))
            case None => InternalServerError

          }

        }

        case None => Future(Unauthorized) //Wrap it
      }

    })
}
```

}

This is simplification of your code, with some comments. I hope this is enough to grab the idea:

```
 Future(Option("validCredentials")).flatMap {
   case Some(credential) => Future("OK")
   case None => Future("Unauthorized")
 }
 //Future[Option[String]].flatMap(Option[String] => Future[String])
 //Future[A].flatMap(A => Future[B]) //where A =:= Option[String] and B =:= String
```

Answer (score 0):

Future("Unauthorized") this is not valid please use Future.successful(Ok("OK"))
Future.successful(BadRequest(Unauthorized))